# Google Search Console fails to crawl Youtube embed video

Tags: video, iframe, youtube, embed, google-search-console

In *Google Search Console* => *URL Inspection*, I enter my url:
https://www.phpcrudgenerator.com/tutorials/generate-admin-read-lists, then launch the *Live Test*.

My page embeds a Youtube video, but if I click *VIEW TESTED PAGE*, the screenshot shows that Googlebot failed to load it:

> Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available

A Google search with this message shows many web pages indexed with it instead of their video.

I tried to change / remove my Content-Security-Policy,
I added JSON-LD VideoObject
I tried to replace the youtube iFrame with `<embed>` or `<object>`

Everything has failed.

Any idea?